# Traverse Array and Display In Bullet Points

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to traverse this array and display, 'comment' as bullet points.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [comment] => a
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [comment] => c
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [depth] => 0
                            [child_count] => 0
                            [children] => 
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [comment] => d
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [depth] => 0
                            [child_count] => 0
                            [children] => 
                        )

                )

            [depth] => 1
            [child_count] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [comment] => b
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [comment] => e
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [7] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                            [comment] => g
                                            [parent_id] => 5
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [8] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 8
                                                            [comment] => h
                                                            [parent_id] => 7
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [9] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => 8
                                                                            [comment] => h
                                                                            [parent_id] => 8
                                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [10] => Array
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [id] => 8
                                                                                            [comment] => h
                                                                                            [parent_id] => 9
                                                                                            [depth] => 0
                                                                                            [child_count] => 0
                                                                                            [children] => 
                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                            [depth] => 1
                                                                            [child_count] => 1
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [depth] => 2
                                                            [child_count] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [depth] => 3
                                            [child_count] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [depth] => 4
                            [child_count] => 1
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [comment] => f
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [depth] => 0
                            [child_count] => 0
                            [children] => 
                        )

                )

            [depth] => 5
            [child_count] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Good for you, madphp. If you run into any problems when trying to code it, let us know ;)

Comment: @Ryan i dont want to muddy the waters by showing my attempt. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, my **hierTree()** function by default prints nested **ul** or **ol** lists, for an undetermined depth of nested arrays, this function will work out of the box for the example array provided in your question.

```
function hierTree($arr, $tag = 'ul', $key = 'comment', $lvl = 0)
{
    $tabs = (!$lvl)? '': str_repeat("\t", $lvl);
    reset($arr);
    echo "$tabs<$tag>\n";
    while (list(, $v) = each($arr))
    {   
        echo "$tabs\t<li>";
        echo "{$v[$key]}";
        if (count($v['children']))
        {   
            echo "\n";
            hierTree($v['children'], $tag, $key, $lvl +1);
            echo "$tabs\t";
        }   
        echo "</li>\n";
    }   
    echo "$tabs</$tag>\n";
}

hierTree($tree);
```

The output of this function will be *nicely indented* for it to be easily readable.

Also, If you do `hierTree($tree, 'ol'); you will get an ordered list. Id you do hierTree($tree, 'ol', 'id');` You will get an ordered tree and the **id** field will be print instead of the default **comment** one.

---

**Inserting classes.**

If you want to have different classes per **list** element so you can more easily style on CSS. (although I would recomment to use CSS direct descendant selectors (“>”))

```
function hierTree($arr, $tag = 'ul', $key = 'comment', $lvl = 0)
{
    $tabs = (!$lvl)? '': str_repeat("\t", $lvl);
    reset($arr);
    echo "$tabs<$tag class=\"depth$lvl\">\n"; // ← The change is there.
    while (list(, $v) = each($arr))
    {   
        echo "$tabs\t<li>";
        echo "{$v[$key]}";
        if (count($v['children']))
        {   
            echo "\n";
            hierTree($v['children'], $tag, $key, $lvl +1);
            echo "$tabs\t";
        }   
        echo "</li>\n";
    }   
    echo "$tabs</$tag>\n";
}
```

This slightly modified version will print a **depthN** class per **list** element.
So you can then target their **LI**s by a simple CSS rule such as `ul.depth1 > li { ...`.

Comment: Hey Mario. How can I insert a class into the <li> so I can change style depending on depth of element.

Comment: I would recomment using CSS direct descendant selectors, anyway, I have modified my answer to provide the feature you ask for.

Comment: Forgot to mention, my edit inserts classes in the list element itself ant not items, because you can access the items more easily and the code will be smaller. There is no need for same class for many lis when they are all at the same level.

Comment: havent tested this yet. I will this week.

Comment: Come on what have you been doing, quit partying and work... geez.

Comment: i wish it where partying. :-)

Comment: mario i had to leave this for a while. If i need to add <div> tags and <span> tags inside each <li> is it easy to change your solution. I want to add other items such as comment date time, author etc. But still keeping the same tree structure.

Comment: i've created another question. Can you have a look when you get a chance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472550/traverse-array-and-display-in-lidiv-markup

Answer (score 2):

You need a little bit of recursion

```
function traverse_array($array)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($array as $element)
    {
        echo '<li>';
        if(isset($element['comment']))
        {
            echo $element['comment'];
        }
        if(is_array($element['children']) && count($element['children']) > 0)
        {
            traverse_array($element['children']);
        }

        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

traverse_array($the_big_array);
```

Comment: haha yea thanks. its untested... =/ so hopefully it works, but it should at the very least be a good start

Comment: actually ive already fixed two issues on it. I need a stack overflow test environment for PHP issues. kinda like that jsfiddle stuff

Comment: Just so happens I bought PHPFiddle.com the other day for that very reason. Stay tuned ;)

Comment: you could use is_array instead of isset

Comment: @beerwin true, I'm not sure that performance comparisons of is_array, isset, and is_empty is in scope though...

Comment: @AlienWebguy francis@yaconiello.com - add me to your alpha / beta / most interested in this product list for phpfiddle

Comment: yes, but what if the children element is not an array, but a string, or even worse, a number?