# Traverse Array and Display in <li><div> markup

Tags: php

I want to traverse this array and display, in bulleted divs. I know this look a lot suspicious, like do it yourself. But I cant get past the nested foreach problem, especially, when it comes to deph of the threads. I got an answer in a previous question [Traverse Array and Display In Bullet Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288081/traverse-array-and-display-in-bullet-points), but i'm not sure how to change the markup in the solution that was given.... or if its possible. Below is the array, and i have a link to the pastebin of the markup i would like, but would be awesome if the markup can be changed easily in the future, ie markup views separated from logic.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [comment_title] => comment title
            [comment] => a
            [comment_date] => comment date
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [comment_title] => comment title
                            [comment] => this is another comment
                            [comment_date] => comment date
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [depth] => 0
                            [child_count] => 0
                            [children] => 
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [comment_title] => comment title
                            [comment] => this is a third comment
                            [comment_date] => comment date
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [depth] => 0
                            [child_count] => 0
                            [children] => 
                        )

                )

            [depth] => 1
            [child_count] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [comment_title] => comment title
            [comment] => this is yet another comment
            [comment_date] => comment date
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [comment_title] => comment title
                            [comment] => another comment
                            [comment_date] => comment date
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [7] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 7
                                            [comment_title] => comment title
                                            [comment] => Hey im a comment!
                                            [comment_date] => 1/1/1970
                                            [parent_id] => 5
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [8] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 8
                                                            [comment_title] => comment title
                                                            [comment] => I disagree
                                                            [comment_date] => 1/1/1970
                                                            [parent_id] => 7
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [9] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => 8
                                                                            [comment_title] => comment title
                                                                            [comment] => My comment is...
                                                                            [comment_date] => 1/1/1970
                                                                            [parent_id] => 8
                                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [10] => Array
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [id] => 8
                                                                                            [comment_title] => comment title
                                                                                          [comment] => Hey im a comment!
                                                                                   [comment_date] => 1/1/1970
                                                                                            [parent_id] => 9
                                                                                            [depth] => 0
                                                                                            [child_count] => 0
                                                                                            [children] => 
                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                            [depth] => 1
                                                                            [child_count] => 1
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                            [depth] => 2
                                                            [child_count] => 1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [depth] => 3
                                            [child_count] => 1
                                        )

                                )

                            [depth] => 4
                            [child_count] => 1
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [comment_title] => comment title
                            [comment] => This is the last comment
                            [comment_date] => 1/1/1970
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [depth] => 0
                            [child_count] => 0
                            [children] => 
                        )

                )

            [depth] => 5
            [child_count] => 2
        )

)
```

Here is the markup i want to use. http://pastebin.com/MBppxiC7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code that I provided you before, just try adding pieces of code and you will get how it works. Once you begin understanding the code I made, you will be able to extend it and add your extra features.

Comment: Hey Mario. Yeah, ive had another look and I guess where Im having the issue is the $key = 'comment'. How can I bring in another array value. If I add in a comment created date and comment title, into the array.

Comment: I am sorry for not answering, I had to go out, I am glad that you could figure out on your own. Thanks for picking my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try making a recursive function which checks for the child_count and if its >1 then function will again traverse the children key of that array to get the children. Basically you can create a function and can call it when needed.